# Redshift - Filter out rows that are blank to left or right of a character

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to check for a condition that excludes rows that has a empty value either to the left of a hyphen (-) or to the right.

In the below sample, I need to filter out rows 2 and 3 since it is either blank to the left of the hyphen or to the right.

Trying to do this using Redshift.

**Sample data:**

```
data_set
apple - banana
 - banana
apple -
```

**Expected output:**

```
data_set
apple - banana
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `like`:

```
where column like '%_-_%'
```

The `_` is a wildcard that matches a character, but the character has to be there.

Note:  You may need to trim the column value first, if spaces might appear before or after the hyphen.